# Finding all subgraphs of depth 2 Networkx

Tags: networkx

I have a huge graph in networkx and I would like to get all the subgraphs of depth 2 from each node. Is there a nice way to do that using buildin function in networkx?

Comment: what is a subgraph of depth 2?

Comment: I have heard them being called ego-graphs. Think facebook and friends of friends for a given user.

Comment: And the function in `networkx` is conveniently called `ego_graph`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I said in the comment, `networkx.ego_graph` fits the bill. You just need to make sure that you set the radius to 2 (default is 1):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

# create some test graph
graph = nx.erdos_renyi_graph(1000, 0.005)

# create an ego-graph for some node
node = 0
ego_graph = nx.ego_graph(graph, node, radius=2)

# plot to check
nx.draw(ego_graph); plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is a useful graph function. Let's say you have an ego graph for all of the nodes in a network with depth 2. Let's also say that you have a dollar amount associated with each edge. Finally, let's say you are interested in 5 particular ego graphs and how many dollars are associated with them for a depth of 2, then sum those amounts. I think you can easily add up all the edges for each ego graph then add them together. However, you don't want to double count amounts. So if an edge appears in, say, 3 ego networks, it should be counted as one. Is there a Networkx function for this?

Comment: @spacedustpi No, but just get the `set` of all edges in the 5 ego-graphs and then sum.

Comment: Great, elegant, simple idea. Don't know why I struggled with this for the past few days.

Comment: @spacedustpi Glad to help. Next time, don't struggle so long. Make a good MWE that illustrates your problem and then hit SO or one of the stack exchanges. Half of my questions on here were problems that weren't hard to solve; it just took another pair of eyes to see the solution. We all run into problem like that every so often.

Comment: Definitely will. Didn't think there would be much NetworkX support here. As it turns out it was not necessarily a NetworkX solution. Thanks.