# Generating NetworkX subgraphs based on distance

Tags: python, social-networking, networkx

I want to choose any given node and build a subgraph for that node based on what distance degree I want. I need to input a node's ID, and specify the degree ( 1 = only direct friends, 2 = direct friends, and friends of friends, 3 = direct friends, friends of friends, friends of friends of friends and so on...) and generate a subgraph for that node's social network to that degree.

Does anyone know a good way to do this in networkx?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

btw the word 'degree' has a specific meaning in networks.  It's the number of neighbors a node has.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding all subgraphs of depth 2 Networkx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43529532/finding-all-subgraphs-of-depth-2-networkx)

Comment: I found the feature I'm looking for like, right after I posted this. It is the networkx ego_graph feature.
https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.generators.ego.ego_graph.html

Answer (score 1):

I found the feature I'm looking for like, right after I posted this. It is the networkx ego_graph feature. networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/